# At hand or in hand?

Tags: grammaticality

Which is a better or a correct statement ? At the end of the day I have rs 1000 at hand or in hand ?

Comment: Well, it depends what you want to say. At the end of the day, you have money in hand. When you're prepared, you have what you need at hand.

Comment: Please try checking a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

When you are waiting outside the door of a friend who has agreed to lend you the money, you have the rs 1000 at hand (within your impending control). When you walk away clutching the money, you have the rs 1000 in hand (in your physical possession).

But there are further figurative uses of both expressions. When you deposit the money in your sock drawer indefinitely, you may say that you have the rs 1000 at hand (within physical reach). And when your spouse reminds you that you must pay Mr. Corleone rs 1000 within 24 hours or face the consequences, you may respond that you have the situation in hand (in circumstances to permit favorable resolution) because the resolution of the business at hand (deserving immediate attention) is in hand (in preparation) and can be settled as soon as Mr. Corleone's representative appears on hand (in attendance).

Comment: I would think *to hand* better than *at hand* there, but neither is wrong.